# If $\xi$ is a vector bundle and $f^{*}(\xi)$ is the bundle induced by $f$ then $f^{*}(\xi)$ is orientable.

Tags: vector-bundles

Let $\xi = \pi : E \rightarrow X$ be a vector bundle and $f: Y \rightarrow X$ a continuous map.

Let $E' \subset Y \times E$ be the set of all $(y,e)$ with $f(y) = \pi(e)$. We can define a vector bundle $f^*(\xi)= \pi' : E' \rightarrow Y$ with $\pi'(y,e)=y$ and $\pi'^{-1}(y)=\{ (y,e)| e\in \pi^{-1}(f(y)\}$.

Also  $\overline f: E' \rightarrow E$  $\quad$ $\overline f (y,e)=e$ induces a bundle map $(\overline f, f)$ which is an isomorphism on each fibre.

I need to show that if $\xi$ is orientable then $f^*(\xi)$ is also orientable but i don't know how to check the compatibility condition in the definition of orientability.

Comment: Do you know the relationship between the transition functions of $E$ and the transition functions of $f^*E$?